# Getting EOF error response when doing HEAD request

Tags: rest, go, eof, http-error

I am trying to do a HEAD request at "https://speed.hetzner.de/100MB.bin" to get the metadata of the file. I am served with an EOF error response. However, the GET request is successful for the same URL.

What could be the possible reasons?

I suspect that the server has blocked HEAD requests, but how do I verify it?

PS: adding the code:

```
func BuildRequest(method string, url string) (*http.Request, error) {
    r, err := http.NewRequest(method, url, nil)
    r.Header.Set("User-Agent", "my app")
    return r, err
}

func (m *FileMeta) Fetch(url string) error {
    r, err := BuildRequest(http.MethodHead, url)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    resp, err := HTTPClient().Do(r)

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    defer resp.Body.Close()
}
```

Error screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Q: did you confirm that you can get a valid HEAD response independent of Go (did you try curl, Postman or equivalent?  Did they response with HEADER information?)  Q: Did you find a viable "Go" code solution (e.g. `http.Head()`)? Please let us know!

Comment: I did try with Postman, it didn't respond with HEADER information.
I tried Curl, it says "Empty reply from server".

Comment: ```
resp, err := http.Head("https://speed.hetzner.de/100MB.bin")
 if err != nil {
  return err
 }
```
tried the above code as you suggested. it throws the same "EOF" error.

Comment: Cool - thank you.  So it sounds like your original surmise is correct: 1) Your code is OK: you're not "doing anything wrong" (like trying to read a "Body" that isn't there).  2) Rather, that particular URL (speed.hetzner.de) is blocking (or at least refusing to process) HEAD requests.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't shown us any code ...

...but sounds like you're trying to read an HTTP "response" from a HEAD request (instead of only accessing the HTTP response headers).

Per the RFC:

> https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.4
>
> The HEAD method is identical to GET except that the server MUST NOT
> return a message-body in the response. The metainformation contained
> in the HTTP headers in response to a HEAD request SHOULD be identical
> to the information sent in response to a GET request. This method can
> be used for obtaining metainformation about the entity implied by the
> request without transferring the entity-body itself. This method is
> often used for testing hypertext links for validity, accessibility,
> and recent modification.

In other words, the response to a HEAD request doesn't have a body.  If you try to read one, you'll get an EOF.  I suspect that's what's happening here.

---

Thank you for updating your question with this code.  It looks like you're using Go.

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38563299/421195):

```
res, err := http.Head("https://golang.org")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
println(res.StatusCode)
```

And remember: *res will have no Body*.

---

**ADDENDUM**

– Rajesh Sethi

> I did try with Postman, it didn't respond with HEADER information.
> I tried Curl, it says "Empty reply from server".
>
> The code above, `resp, err := http.Head("speed.hetzner.de/100MB.bin")`, throws the same "EOF" error.

– paulsm4

> Cool - thank you. So it sounds like your original surmise is correct:
>
> 1. Your code is OK: you're not "doing anything wrong" (like trying to read a "Body" that isn't there).
> 2. Rather, that particular URL
>    (speed.hetzner.de) is blocking (or at least refusing to process) HEAD requests.

Comment: it fails at HTTPClient().Do(r) and returns error

Comment: Sooooo .... you're trying to make the HEAD request from Go.  SUGGESTIONS: 1) Try "HEAD" using a *different* method, e.g. [curl](https://curl.se/) or [Postman](https://www.postman.com/downloads/).  Verify "it works". 2) Next, try this example, using `http.Head()`): https://stackoverflow.com/a/38563299/421195, 3) If you specify the method, be sure to use the Go const [HEAD](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#pkg-constants)